# What is happening inside split()?

Tags: java

```
String[] tokens = str.split("[^\\p{Alpha}]+");
```

I cannot get this format `"[^\\p{Alpha}]+"`. If anyone can stepwise break down this, thanks in advance

Comment: Split on anything (consecutively) not of the class alphabetical.

Comment: https://regular-expressions.mobi/posixbrackets.html?wlr=1
It’s a posix character class inside an ‘any character not in’ block, `[^…]`. The `+` means ‘one or more’. I think `\P{Alpha}+` would do the same but I don’t have an IDE to test right now.

Comment: The details of [Java's regex are part of the docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)  `\p{Alpha}`  is defined to be `[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]`.

Comment: The [] and the + are standard regex, you should consider reading about it.  In Java, the "\\" construct is a *string* escape (not regex) and it is equivalent to a single \, so the actual string is "[^\p{Alpha}]+".  This is something that trips *everybody* up when dealing with regex, even experts mess it up on occasion.